# Algebraic Structure of $(\mathbb{N}, \max)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Determine which algebraic structure $(\mathbb{N},\max)$ is, where $\max$ is the function that gets 2 elements and return the biggest element.

I have started with associativity:

We need to prove that for all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$ $$\max(\max(a,b),c)=\max(a,\max(b,c))$$

I am trying to generalize the cases so I will not need to check every case.
 So W.L.G., $c$ is the biggest element that is $a<b<c$ therefore:
 $\max(\max(a,b),c)=c=\max(a,\max(b,c))$ but it seems that the argument is flawed but I can not put the finger on the problem

Comment: I think you are being misled by the word group in the question.  $(\Bbb N,\max)$ is not a group.  The operation is associative as you have shown, and $0$or $1$ is an identity (depending on whether you have $0 \in \Bbb N$), but there are no inverses.  You should have some other algebraic structures you have studied in the course and this should fit (at least) one of them.  Without the $\max$ this could be a total order, a partial order, a countable set, or some other things.  None of these have an operation required, so look through your structures for something that needs an operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, your proof for associativity is flawed

The equality
$$\max(\max(a,b),c)=\max(a,\max(b,c))$$
is not symmetric in $a,b,c$ so you cannot use WLOG in the way you did.

**Hint**

Case 1: $a\leq b$, then $\max(\max(a,b),c)=\max(b,c)$.

Also, you have $a \leq b \Rightarrow a \leq \max(b,c)$.  Thus
$$\max(a,\max(b,c))$$

Case 2: $a >b$. Show the same way that both sides are equal to $\max(a,c)$.

**P.S.**Alternatelly, you can prove that both sides are equal to $\max\{ a, b, c \}$.

Comment: So $(\mathbb{N},\max)$ is just a magma, right?

Comment: @Charter it is associative as N.S showed and $0\in \mathbb{N}$ is the unit element, but there is no inverse $max(a,0)\neq 0$  as $a>0; \forall a\in \mathbb{B}$ so it is a Monoid

Comment: @gbox ups, you're right. I misread the answer and I thought $\max$ wasn't associative.